# Access to filter_name property with python

Tags: python, scripting, panel

Is it possible to set UI list filter with python?

[image: vertex group filter]

Comment: Maybe, it is part of the UI list so you would have to get the panel instance in the properties area of the current screen. If the user has multiple properties visible, which one do you want to change? You do realise that it is only filters the list displayed in that one panel? You can get a filtered list of vertex groups in your script without touching this property.

Comment: Let say that I want to change the filter name for all "vertex group" tab. How do I get the panel instance? I don't want to make my own ui list, I just wondering how to acces to this property, I couldn't find it